# Faster way to update databases through arrays or objects

Tags: javascript, rest

I am simply doubtful about the performance result of different approaches.

My process is this:

1. Have a rest call that returns a (global) array of objects called "projectsarray" that is a copy of the database table i.e. a list of projects with their ids, name, budget, etc.
2. Cycle through the array and show the list of projects on a html page (anything like laravel/nodejs ajax/vue is fine)
3. Change one detail of one project sending a(n async in node) rest call in order to update the project in the database and substitute ONLY the single project in my global object, so to see it updated client-side asap

I can:

1. Have a rest call for every project(row) in the table at the beginning, to retrieve the list and a rest call for the single project when I update it. (very bad in my opinion, I didn't even try)
2. Have my returned array, and use find()/findIndex()/indexOf() client-side to update the single project in the array client-side and update the database via rest call as described
3. Make the array a hash made of the projects ids and the projects objects so that I can directly chose the right projectsarray id instead of cycling with find/index functions (but I guess it will be same speed and less elegance)
4. ..or even make an array of arrays with single object, adding to the object an array-id property that gives me the index of the array like:

```
[0]:[{id: 1; name: project1; budget: 1000; ... array-id: 0;}
[1]:[{id: 23; name: project23; budget: 500; ... array-id: 1;}
..
[999]:[{id: 1245; name: project1245; budget: 600; ... array-id: 999;}
```

4. (..continued..) so that I can just update the projectsarray[999] (instead of cycling? does it cycle anyways?)

So, what is the standard or faster methodology, which function is the most performant, what approach is the most elegant?

Maybe I spent a lot of words when there is just one way, but as a beginner for me it's not easy to see the only one.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to fetch a number of projects and then be able to update them one by one whenever necessary. An optimization you could do is adding pagination. Fetching 20 projects at a time for example. This would improve loading times as usually you don't want all 1000+ objects on the page from a UX perspective.

Comment: Thanks Vasil, no I am only concerned about update speed. Projects could be 10 or 1000, it is another matter for me now, I can limit that at the beginning with adding LIMIT to the SQL statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the numbers for the answer, but I can tell you what I generally use for this: solution 2 with findIndex Array method.

There's a caveat with solution 3, is that order is not guaranteed in objects. If you do not care about it it's OK to use it. The typical implementation uses something like lodash's methods .keyBy to build the object and then .values to transform back into array (if needed). But I find there's a lot of manipulation uneeded, just to avoid the use of a findIndex (what if the user only consults?). I don't see an advantage here as Arrays are just list-like objects where keys are index numbers, so pretty much what a findIndex does, accessing a property name does too (if you know your index in solution 2). If you don't know your index and you're sure that updates will be made into your project list, then you might have a case for solution 3.

For solution 4, I've never seen it and I don't see the benefit of array-id vs id (provided you do have an id and it's unique).

Edit : And for persistence, a rest call with PUT/PATCH the detail. There's no avoiding in the frontend to modify the original array (typically a .splice(x, 1, y) where x is the index and y is the new object), but many frontend frameworks handle the change detection for you, you do not need to make a shallow or deep copy of the whole array object, but you better check how it's handled.